# Open linearized pdf on mupdf in android

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

I am using mupdf library in android to view pdf files in private memory of application. In my application first i download the linearized pdf file in private memory of application then pass the pdf uri to MuPDFActivity.java.

Now i want to open my linearized pdf in linearized way i.e when user swap views pdf during that in background pdf download process continue.
I am not quite clear about the process to open linearized pdf file using mupdf file. If you guys can help me , it will be a highly appreciable.

Answer (score 4):

Currently (Feb 2013) MuPDF ignores the fact that PDFs are linearised. It jumps straight to the end to read the trailer/xref dictionary there. This means that MuPDF wouldn't be able to open a PDF file until it had entirely downloaded anyway.

I have code on a local branch to add this facility to MuPDF, but it's not ready for release yet, hence it's not in 1.2. Watch out for it in 1.3 due in August, hopefully. Or watch the git repo to see it appear earlier (other priorities permitting).